# Why is my Dist folder not existing despite being there in my project?

Tags: angular

have encountered this question and can't figure-out way around it. Which step might i have gone amiss ..? help

```
sudo npx ngh --dir=dist/Git-Hub
*** Dist folder does not exist. Check the dir --dir parameter or build the project first!
```

*** An error occurred!

> { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access
>   '/home/benson/Downloads/Angular/Giphy/dist/Git-Hub']   errno: -2,
>   code: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'access',

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First run `ng build` and check whether the dist folder exists. If not add this line

```
 "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
```

to compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json file.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  }
```

Comment: still bringing this error `*** Dist folder does not exist. Check the dir --dir parameter or build the project first!

*** An error occurred!

{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/home/benson/Downloads/Angular/Giphy/dist/Git-Hub']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'access',
  path: '/home/benson/Downloads/Angular/Giphy/dist/Git-Hub' }
`

Comment: no .. i have run --build --prod and finally, the error appears when running sudo npx ngh --dir=dist/{project-name}